# How to change the post-login page using django-registration?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using django-registration and django-registration_defaults (for the templates) in my app.  How do I change the page the user sees after he/she logs in?  I looked through the documentation but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

This redirects to home url.